# Run jenkins behind nginx

Tags: java, jenkins, nginx-location

i want to run jenkins behind nginx tried following step

```
      location /jenkins {
                rewrite ^/jenkins(.*) $1 break;
                proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/jenkins;
            }
```

with localhost:8000 and localhost:8000/jenkins tried both

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --prefix=$PREFIX --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"

jenkins port changed to 8000 ...
but getting 500 server error

if i don't add this line "rewrite ^/jenkins(.*) $1 break;"
then getting 404 server error

sudo netstat -tulpn --- saw there on 8000 program is running

i want "location /jenkins" not "location /"

Comment: Check out [This](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/)

Comment: threre only l"location /"
but i want to run nginx along with other server ..